# Show/Hide WebViews in Android

Tags: java, android, webview

I have multiple `WebViews` stored in a `HashMap` which I need to be able to show/hide at any time.

When a row in a `ListView` is tapped, I need to show the `WebView` associated with that row and hide all the others. The other `WebViews` cannot be destroyed as I do not wish to unload their contents.

Is this possible?

Creation and storage of the `WebView` in one `Fragment`:

```
public WebView createWebView(Long id) {
    WebView wv = new WebView(getActivity());
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(registerCredentialsChangedCallback(function(credentials) {if (credentials.length >= 1) {window.location.href = 'callback:' + credentials;} else {alert('Error: callback set by registerCredentialsChangedCallback was given null string');}})) ()");
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    wv.loadUrl(makeViewerURL(id));

    webViews.put(id, wv);

    return wv;
}
```

`onCreate` in another `Fragment`. I'm using an `interface` to pass the id via the `Activity` to the `Fragment` where the `WebView` should be displayed:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_directory, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dbHelper.getViewers(), new String[] { "description", "_id" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Long id = adapter.getItemId(i);

            mCallback.onViewerSelected(id);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

XML Layout of View which should contain WebView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - but you need to have a key value pairs of id and `WebView`.

```
private Map<Long, View> mWebViews = new HashMap<Long, View>();

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Long id = adapter.getItemId(i);
            if(mViews.contains(id))
               mWebView = mViews.get(id)
            else
               mWebView = createWebView();
        }
    });
```

Then you just need to find the corresponding `WebView` which the user selected in List and make it visible. In order to hide the `WebView` you need to use:

```
mWebView.setVisibility(View.Gone);
```

Addenda: instead of webView in your xml file, use a frameLayout such as:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/web_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="420dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip" />
```

And then in the code add the WebView to Framelayout:

```
FrameLayout mWebContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.web_container);
webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
mWebContainer.addView(webView);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this! One other thing I think I need to do is set the height and width of the WebView when I create it. Do I need to do that in the WebView constructor?

Comment: The `Map` and the `ListView` are in different classes so this wouldn't quite work. I'm passing the Id to the other `Fragment` via an `interface` in the `Activity`, then I can use this in the other `Fragment` class to find/create it.

Comment: If you do not have any xml layout where you can attach the webView to a FrameLayout or something, then I think you need to set them when you create the View.

Comment: what if you make the map, `public static`, so that you can use it where you want.

Comment: I've posted my XML Layout above. Guessing I don't need the `WebView` part anymore though because I'm creating them programatically. What do I need to put the WebViews into? Just a view? I only need to use the Map in this one place so It's not a huge issue.